# Query optimization: how to efficiently occlude overridden records?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, query

Imagine a table with roughly a couple of billion rows.  A simplified schema for the table would be

```
started_on: datetime
recorded_on: datetime
image_id: integer
```

It's indexed by `started_on`.

One quirk of the data is that there can be many records with identical `started_on` values but they may have different `recorded_on` and `image_id` values.  Further, for a given `started_on`, we only want the most recently recorded record.

Currently we get this by

1) pulling all the records within the `started_on` range, and then

2) using code to grab out the most recently `recorded_on` record for each `started_on`.

This works fine, but seems like a waste because we're serializing and sending all those extra records to our app.

Is there an efficient way to accomplish the job of occluding the overridden records in our initial query?

Comment: Does your query want the result for a single `(sign_id, started_on) ` pair or for many?

Comment: For many pairs.  Thinking about this, I should probably leave out sign_id, which is a distraction.  The main thing is to input a range for started_on and then get the last recorded image_id for each started_on in the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, typically the most efficient way is to use `distinct on ()`

```
select distinct on (started_on) started_on, recorded_on, image_id
from the_table
order by started_on, recorded_on desc
where started_on between ...;
```

Comment: This does the trick and is efficient.